# Strange SFML behavior

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm currently trying to write a button class. It takes 2 textures, `m_texture` and `m_onHover`, and its caption, which should be automatically centered. The function `update()` takes care of selecting the correct texture.

```
class button : public sf::Drawable
{
private:
    const sf::Texture *m_texture;
    const sf::Texture *m_onHover;
    sf::Sprite m_sprite;

public:
    button(); 

    sf::Text m_caption; // public to allow easy formating, see centerCaption()

    bool mouseIsOver() const;
    void update();

    void setPosition(sf::Vector2f position);
    void setPosition(float x, float y);

    void centerCaption();

    // Access functions
    void setTexture(const sf::Texture &texture) { m_texture = &texture;     m_sprite.setTexture(*m_texture); }
    void setonHoverTexture(const sf::Texture &texture) { m_onHover = &texture; }
    void setCaption(sf::String text)    { m_caption.setString(text);        centerCaption(); }
    void setFontSize(unsigned int size) { m_caption.setCharacterSize(size); centerCaption(); }
    void setFont(sf::Font& font) { m_caption.setFont(font); }

private:
    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const;
};

bool button::mouseIsOver() const
{
    if (m_sprite.getGlobalBounds().contains(sf::Vector2f(sf::Mouse::getPosition())))    // creating a float vector for contains() because getPosition gives int vector
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Everything seems to be working, but the mouse position at which `mouseIsOver()` returns true seems to be moved 40 pixels above the sprite. The values in the rect from `getGlobalBounds()` seem to be correct when printed in the console.

Unluckily I dont have enough reputation to post a screenshot.

Comment: I don't know SFML well enough to help with your problem, but, there is another [`Mouse::getPosition`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Mouse.php#ac368680f797b7f6e4f50b5b7928c1387) that works with relation to the window. Maybe try it an see if you get a better result.

Comment: @glampert I tried it in fullscreen so that shouldn't be the problem. Also the position of the text, which is calculated using the global boundings, seems to be off for the same amount of pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cursor position should be translated to the proper coordinate system. Basically you need to use `sf::RenderTarget::mapPixelToCoords` (available in `sf::Renderwindow` by inheritance). For more details, have a look at the documentation and [§Coordinates conversions](http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/graphics-view.php#coordinates-conversions) of the official tutorial.

Also, you might want to consider making your button class inherit from `sf::Transformable` so that you don't have to manage the position/rotation/scale/... yourself. Have a look at [Creating a SFML-like entity](http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/graphics-vertex-array.php#creating-a-sfml-like-entity)