# Getting clicked position using SFML

Tags: sfml

I'm currently learning SFML on my own, and trying to figure out how to print out the position of the clicked area at `bposX` and `bposY` in the `pollevent` section. Thi s is my codes:

---

```
sf::RectangleShape smallRectangle (float width = 1.0f, float height = 1.0f, 
                                sf::Vector2f position = sf::Vector2f(1.0f,1.0f),
                                const sf::Color& myFillColor = sf::Color(0,51, 51)
                                )
{
  sf::RectangleShape sboard;
  sf::Vector2f myRectangleSize(width, height);
  sboard.setSize(myRectangleSize);
  sboard.setPosition(position);
  sboard.setFillColor(myFillColor);
  return sboard;
}
```

---

```
case sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed:
                switch(event.mouseButton.button)
                    case sf::Mouse::Left:
                    {
                        float bposX = sboard.getPosition().x;
                        float bposY = sboard.getPosition().y;
                        cout << "Current Position : ";
                        cout << bposX << " " << bposY << endl;
                    break;
                    }
```

---

```
for(int i=0; i < sgridSize; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < sgridSize; j++)
    {
        window.draw(sgrid[i][j]);
        sf::FloatRect sgridBounds = sgrid[i][j].getGlobalBounds();
        if(sgridBounds.contains((sf::Vector2f)pointerPos))
        {
            shighlightCell.setPosition(sgrid[i][j].getPosition());
            window.draw(shighlightCell);
            if(sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left))
            {
                sgrid[i][j].setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I click in rectangle it only displays 1 1, based on my Vector2f position.

Comment: Cool. What is the problem?

Comment: when I click in the rectangle, it supposed to display clicked position in the cmd. instead, it only display the position of my Vector2f value. and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange SFML behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25149152/strange-sfml-behavior)

Comment: Have a look at my answer [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25164949/520217). I'm pretty sure that's exactly your problem.

Comment: sorry, Im not quite sure. still trying to figure out. yours looks quite complicated. my program is just simple beginner stuff.

Comment: @maramugamsaramamam read the answer and the links it contains. It should give you enough insight even if you're just a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm reading your code properly, `sboard` is a `sf::RectangleShape`. Chances are you actually want the position of the mouse, not this rectangle. Mouse position is given through the static function `sf::Mouse::getPosition()` which gives coordinates relative to desktop or `sf::Mouse::getPosition(window)` which will give you the position of the mouse relative to a `sf::Window` or `sf::RenderWindow` instance.

I suggest reading through the tutorials on the SFML website while you're learning the basics. [This one is immediately useful](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/window-inputs.php).

Comment: ok, I understand, and thanks for link. But what if I want the position of the rectangle? how to print out the array position? Ive tried this, vector < vector<int> > vec; vec=sgrid[i][j]; but gives error.

Comment: The position of the clicked rectangle, you mean?

Comment: Get and store the position of the mouse to a Vector2i. Once it is stored, iterate over the rectangles in your grid, and check if the mouse vector sits in the current rectangle's bounds. If it does, return that rectangle.

Comment: That's what I would do, anyway... there are many ways to accomplish that :)

Comment: Thanks man, I get the ide of what u said to get the position using getpos.x and y. and store it. and print it out. I missed couple of things in sfml, like vector2f stands for float.